# Sanitize user-input in TYPO3 repository function needed?

Tags: typo3, sql-injection, extbase, typo3-9.x, sanitize

I have a TYPO3 repository function that create a like-query.
I wonder, if I have to sanitize the user input to prevent sql-injection and if so, how.
I read s.th. that this is automatically done by the doctrine layer.
I'm on TYPO3 9.5.

Please advice.

Here is my repository-class together with the function:

```
class ProductRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
```

{

```
/**
 * find
 *
 * @return Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryResult
 */


public function findAllLike( $name) {
   $query = $this->createQuery();
   
    $orConstraints = array();
    $orConstraints[] = $query->like('productname',  '%'.$name.'%');
    $orConstraints[] = $query->like('tradename','%'.$name.'%');    

    $constraints[] = $query->logicalOr($orConstraints);       

    return $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to escape your like query
see the documentation on TYPO3 Querybuilder
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#database-query-builder-escape-like-wildcards

Comment: Thanks. I've read this. But how do I sanitize, when I'm already in repository-context. I have used $this->createQuery() before. I don't want to create the whole query (including left joined tables) by hand. Is there any way ?